# jQuery list filter

Tags: jquery, search, filter

I have a requirement where i have to search items onkeyup in a search box from a list , select few and move them to another list. I wrote the following script and this works as expected in firefox and not working in IE9 and chrome. I am new to jQuery and unable to find a fix. Can some one help??. Thanks in advance.

```
//HTML//
<input type="text" id="searchAvailableLabsTxt" class="searchAvailableLabsTxt
searchbox" onkeyup="filter(this)"/>
<select multiple="true" runat="server" id="AvailableGroupLab" class="
AvailableGroupLab availGrpLabs avalLabs"></select>
//HTML

//JQUERY//
function filter(element) {
var value = $(element).val().toLowerCase();

$(".AvailableGroupLab > option").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) > -1) {
        $(this).show();
    }
    else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
}
//JQUERY//
```

Comment: hide/show of options will not work as expected in IE

Answer (score 0):

The problem with code is `hide()` function which does not work in chrome and IE. You can store copy of options as backup and remove the options using `remove()`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fmaLG/1/)**

```
var options = $(".AvailableGroupLab").clone().html();
function filter(element) {
    $('.AvailableGroupLab').html(options);
    var value = $(element).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".AvailableGroupLab option").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) == -1) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way all together where i can get it work on IE, Firefox and Chrome ??

Comment: Check my updated answer with live demo, and tell me how it went?

Comment: That was working for search, however when i search for an item, select and move it to other list and then clear the search box, then the list is blank. It is removing the items from the list which did not match with the input instead of hiding and displaying when the box is empty

Comment: You have to remove, you can store the initial copy of options to reuse on each key up as in demo

Comment: sorry... i did not understand. I have used the code from the fiddle

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and explain the problem you getting?